# Offline mode website have stuff with jquery-ui.min.js file

Tags: jquery, html

I am working for website in offline mode. I am using `jquery-ui.min.js` not CDN but copy code from link, but I am getting error in that `jquery-ui.min.js` code.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: where your code ?

Comment: i am just opening this link any copy code and placing to html file in <script></script>
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: script tag close problem

Answer (score 0):

1.Copy code from https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js link and save it to any js file and use script tag as :

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

`src`contains path to jQuery js file

2. You can also use CDN as :

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Close the `script` tag properly.

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its not closing problem but when we open code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js in browser and copy script code. and then use that code directly in html file it have error. like

 <script>(function(e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],e):e(jQuery)})(function(e){function t(t,s){var n,a,o,r=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"area"===r?(n=t.parentNode,a=n.name,t.href&&a&&"map"===n.nodeName.toLowerCase()?(o=e("img[usemap='#"+a+"']")</script>